# How to know what exactly has happened with array? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, diff

My array is a representation of a textarea lines. 
And while editing textarea I want to know  what exactly has happened with that array.

```
const before= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,      7, 8, 9, 10]
const after = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Here I want to see `after 5th element has added new element 6.5`

```
const before= [           1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const after = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Here I want to see: `before 0th element has added 3 new elements [-2, -1, 0]`.

Also in that way `has deleted`, `has edited`.

In general, at one moment changes only one part of array.

I have seen library `deep-object-diff` it is good for objects, but doesn't do what I need for arrays.

May be I should compare directly multiline text instead of arrays? But app should do it fast, when user types text...

Please, share ideas about the subject.

If you are interested about whole project, it's like annotation tool. While texting in Textarea in Waveform appears new phrases (colored regions of waveform).

[image]

Comment: well, you just need to iterate the arrays. as soon something is different you know the position. Then when the length changed you know if something was added. If the length is the same just count how many elements are different.

Comment: @Lux, I hope there is some existing solutions. Or some optimized ways for do that )